# Access user's text messages on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

Is there a way to access a user's text messages (without an internet connection, obviously...not trying to take the client's messages) and analyze the text within an app?

Totally understandable if there isn't (for security reasons), but I figured i'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, you can only send them :S

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010416-SW1

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you know if that's still the case in 2013?