# How can I get text messages from iPhone to my app. Is it possible or not?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get text messages from iPhone into an app. Is it possible or not? Does Apple support this or not?

Comment: This question has been asked many many times before: [Access user's text messages on iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509626/access-users-text-messages-on-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can send message only no read access to email or SMS them as according to the `iOS` sdk as Access to SMS and email messages isn't available to developers also there is also number of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509626/access-users-text-messages-on-iphone) on SO related this topic. like and There are serious privacy and security concerns with enabling app access to emails and SMS means user data.

Comment: okay thank u for your valuable information